# Am I using onchange incorrectly?

Tags: javascript, forms, onchange

I'm trying to have a value (`key`) that updates to correspond with a number in a textbox (`angle`) divided by a value (`25`). However, for some reason, the `changeMe` function doesn't seem to be executing. Am I using onchange incorrectly?

```
<script type="text/javascript">

function changeMe(x)
{
var y=document.getElementById(x).value;
y = (y/25);
y = (Math.round(y));
document.getElementById(key).value=y;
}
</script>

<form method="POST" action="">
Your Angle: <input type="text" name="angle" id="angle" 
    onchange="changeMe(this.id)" value="0"/>
Key: <span id="key">0</span><br />
</form>
```

Comment: Giving a span the id of "key" is asking for trouble. "KeyResult" or "OutputKey" or "KeyDisplay" would be less likely to produce the error in your code spotted by Tomas.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Change the line

```
document.getElementById(key).value=y;
```

to

```
document.getElementById('key').innerHTML=y;
```

Answer (score 1):

To see if it's being called, just add this as the first line:

```
alert("Hey, I'm being called!");
```

Now, I already see a problem here: in the last line of your function, you're doing `getElementById(key)`, but you should enclose `key` with double quotes. If not, it's being considered a variable instead of a string.

Answer (score 1):

The last line `document.getElementById(key)` should be `document.getElementById("key")`.

By the way you can simplify this a fair bit by passing the `<input>` element directly instead of its id:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function changeMe(angle)
{
    var key = document.getElementById("key");
    key.innerHTML = Math.round(angle.value / 25);
}
</script>

<form method="POST" action="">
Your Angle: <input type="text" name="angle" id="angle" 
    onchange="changeMe(this)" value="0"/>
Key: <span id="key">0</span><br />
</form>
```

Answer (score 1):

The `changeMe(this.id)` bothers me, I am using to seeing just `(this)`, but, the best way to know what is going on is to use either the Web Developer extension in IE8 (I press F12 and it comes up) or, preferably, Firebug, on Firefox, and then you can put in a break point at the beginning of the changeMe function and see what is passed in, as there may be an error.

And the other two already mentioned about the problem with your getElementById.

Answer (score 0):

Try using the suggestion by James Black to use `onchange="changeMe(this)"`, your function becomes simplified

```
function changeMe(x) {
    y = Math.round(x.value/25);
    document.getElementById('key').innerHTML = y;
}
```

Notice the `document.getElementById('key').innerHTML = y`, This will replace the inner html (as the name describes), I think that is what you wanted to use.